# Turning camera vertically (using Angle-Axis rotation)

Tags: c++, view, camera, rotation

I am writing a camera class for OpenGL that is using quaternions and Angle-Axis. I managed to make a function for horizontal rotation (it was easy) but I can't manage to write a working function to rotate it vertically. All my attempts end up by camera rotating hell knows what directions... **I need a formula or code how for my vertical rotation function (*pitchTurn()* in my code).**

```
Here is my current code:

void Camera::yawTurn(const float& angle){
    rotate(angle, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
}

void Camera::pitchTurn(const float& angle){
// need code here
}

void Camera::rotate(const float& angle, const float& x, const float& y, const float& z){
    Quaternionf t;
    t.fromAxisAngle(angle, x, y, z);
    q_ *= t;
    q_.normalize();
}
```

I also wonder if there is any better way to use quaternion for rotations without use Angle-Axis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most likely issue is the order of rotations.

A quaternion product q * r, when viewed as two combined rotations, is applied to the transformed vertices in the order r, q.

Now, if you want to turn the camera around the global Y axis (the axis does not depend on camera orientation), you have to multiply t * q. If you want to turn the camera around the local Y axis (the axis is specified in terms of camera orientation - if you're looking straight down, your "up" vector lies in XZ plane, i.e. has an Y coordinate of 0), you have to multiply q * t.

Typical camera controls rotate around the global Y axis and around the local X axis. So you should make two functions, preRotate and postRotate (or local / global), use global (pre) version in yawTurn and local (post in pitchTurn.

Comment: Yeah, rotating around local X or Z is what I need... **What are the math formulas for that?** Anyone? I'm OK with 2D geometry but when it comes to 3D... I usually miss something and it becomes a mess.

Comment: TO rotate around local X axis, you should construct a rotation around X axis: t.fromAxisAngle(angle, 1, 0, 0), and then post-multiply: q = q * t. So your current rotate works, but you should use another function for your yawTurn.

Comment: WOW. Now I got it :) Maybe I didn't get it yesterday 'coz I was sleepy but THANK YOU!. It's pretty simple, actually (if you understand quaternions, of course. I still have no idea how it works). That's so cool.